# How do I programmatically use an external database?

Tags: 8, database

How do I programmatically use an external database?

```
$databases = array();
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  // Drupal's default credentials here.
  // This is where the Drupal core will store its data.
);
$databases['my_other_db']['default'] = array(
  // Your secondary database's credentials here.
  // You will be able to explicitly connect to this database from your modules.
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Setup the external database on settings.php
2. Select the correct database

   ```
   $con = \Drupal\Core\DatabaseDatabase::getConnection('default','my_other_db');
   ```

I took the example from 
 http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/175/use-multiple-databases-drupal-8.